# Why await response.json() return a promise?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get some data from my server using fecth API with async/await. I know i can do this inside an async function

```js
async function someFunction(url) {
    let response = await fecth(url)
    let data = await response.json()
    // Here I can use the data
    console.log(data) // print the data correctly
    data.map(x => x.key) // works well
}
```

However if I return the data and try to use it in another function, it returns a promise, but why?

```js
function mainFunction() {
    let data = getData(url)
    // Here data is again a promise
    console.log(data) // "Promise {<pending>}"
    data.map(x => x.key) // "Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function"
}

async function getData(url) {
    let response = await fecth(url)
    let data = await response.json()
    console.log(data) // print the data correctly
    return data
}
```

if I use `data = await getData(url)` it works again but my code editor (vscode) says *'await' has no effect on the type of this expression.*, so I'm confused, why I have to await the data again if I'm returning the awaited data?

Comment: It doesn't. Inside the async function, data is the value the promise resolves to. But async functions **always return promises**, that's how they support awaiting inside.

Comment: *"but my code editor (vscode) says 'await' has no effect on the type of this expression."* - That sounds like a mistake.  `await` most certainly does have an effect when used on a `Promise`.  As it stands in the code shown the problem is simply that you're not awaiting `getData(url)`.  (Either with `await` and making `mainFunction` also `async`, or with a `.then()` callback.)

Comment: @David Now I get it. So it's probably a vscode bug, that's what confused me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

> An async function declaration creates an AsyncFunction object. Each time when an async function is called, it returns a new Promise which will be resolved with the value returned by the async function, or rejected with an exception uncaught within the async function.

So, async function always returns a `Promise`

You can use `then` to get the data:

```
mainFunction() {
  const result = getData(url).then(data => data.map(x => x.key))
}
```

Comment: Oh I get it now. So in your example, `result` will still be a Promise, won't it?